# Initialize structs from list of strings

Tags: go, struct, slice

I'm trying to initialize structs from a list of strings, but the compiler is throwing the following error. I'm still learning the language so excuse my ignorance, but is this solved by utilizing type assertion?

> ERROR: v.UberX undefined (type string has no field method UberX)

```
type Galaxy struct {
    UberX     int64
    UberY     int64
}

func main() {
    galaxies := []string{"andromeda", "milkyway", "maffei"}
    for _, v := range galaxies {
        v := &Galaxy{}
    }
    for _, v := range galaxies {
        v.UberX += 1000
        v.UberY += 750
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Galaxy` struct doesn't even store the name, in your attempt there isn't any connection between the names and the struct values. Add the name to the struct:

```
type Galaxy struct {
    Name  string
    UberX int64
    UberY int64
}
```

Next, in your first loop you create a `*Galaxy` value, but you only store it in a local variable `v` which by the way shadows the loop variable `v`:

```
for _, v := range galaxies {
    v := &Galaxy{}
}
```

You need a slice of `Galaxy` or a slice of `*Galaxy` which you can populate:

```
gs := make([]*Galaxy, len(galaxies))
```

Then 1 loop is enough to loop over the galaxy names and populate the `gs` slice:

```
for i, v := range galaxies {
    gs[i] = &Galaxy{
        Name:  v,
        UberX: 1000,
        UberY: 750,
    }
}
```

Verifying the result:

```
for _, v := range gs {
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", v)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/a4kkdx7gX1)):

```
&{Name:andromeda UberX:1000 UberY:750}
&{Name:milkyway UberX:1000 UberY:750}
&{Name:maffei UberX:1000 UberY:750}
```

Recommended to go through the [Golang Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) first to learn the basics.

Comment: No doubt I've got lots of reading to do. Was hoping I could practice some of it in the meantime. My thought process was that the "name" field would be unnecessary if I could initialize the struct with the proper name. Thanks